# Google Appengine Java - getServingUrl from CloudStorage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore, google-cloud-storage

i'm trying to get a servingUrl from a file store in GCS. Here is the code to generate the BlobKey from the cloudStorage data

```
public BlobKey getCloudStorageBlobKey(String bucket_name, String object_name)
{       
    bucket_name = StringUtils.strip(bucket_name, "/");
    object_name = StringUtils.strip(object_name, "/");

    GcsFilename gcs_file = new GcsFilename(bucket_name, object_name);
    String cloudStorageURL = "/gs/" + gcs_file.getBucketName() + "/" + gcs_file.getObjectName();

    BlobstoreService bs = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    BlobKey bk = bs.createGsBlobKey(cloudStorageURL);
    return bk;
}
```

And here the code to get the servingURL

```
public String getThumbUrl(BlobKey blobkey)
{       
    ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(blobkey);

    try
    {
        return ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(options);
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        log().severe("BlobKey " + blobkey + " not valid: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    catch(ImagesServiceFailureException e)
    {
        log().severe("ImageService access error");
        return null;
    }
}
```

When i launch the code with a blobstore BlobKey i get no errors, but when i use this method with a GCS BlobKey i always get

```
IllegalArgumentException
```

Because the [APIs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#using-blobstore-with-gcs) say:

> Note that once you obtain a blobKey for the GCS object, you can pass
>   it around, serialize it, and otherwise use it interchangeably anywhere
>   you can use a blobKey for objects stored in Blobstore. This allows for
>   usage where an app stores some data in blobstore and some in GCS, but
>   **treats the data otherwise identically by the rest of the app**.
>   (However, BlobInfo objects are currently not available for GCS
>   objects.)

Where am i doing wrong?

I saw this method

```
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(googleStorageFileName)
```

but i can't use this because at low-level i want to use blobkey for both BlobStore/GCS.

---

EDIT 1: Here's the stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/index/se5DMfHF. The strange fact is that i do not get an exception message at all

---

EDIT2: Problem solved: analyzing the source code of the

```
ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().getServingUrl(options);
```

method, i found this exception thrown:

```
com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException
```

With a quick search i found the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10051350

Comment: What's the message of the exception? Could you post a stack trace?

Comment: Added the stacktrace, and the solution too :)

Comment: Instead of editing, you may consider to answer your own question. That's the usual thing to do.

Comment: As I see you have found a solution. Could you please provide an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Hi @ZsoltSafrany, there is the url to the anwser with the solution

Comment: I know and it's nice that you updated it after you found the solution. But it would be even nicer if you'd copy/paste that part as a separate answer (and accept it) to make it more obvious that there is a solution for the problem.